# How to retrieve the results from my Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to Deep Learning and using Amazon web services, and I have a (very) basic question to ask.

I seem to have figured out how to run my Python code on Amazon EC2 server via AWS Batch, but I am perplexed because I don't know how to retrieve the code results from my instance, once the server finishes running my code.

For example, say I have a python file `/Users/dev/Code_154.py` ,

and I run `Code_154` on my Amazon EC2 instance. The contents of the code `Code_154.py` is:

```
# define attain_weight_loop function           
def attn_weight_loop(test_i, nlayer, best_model):

    attn_tensor = torch.zeros(test_i.size()[1], nlayer, test_i.size()[0]).float()

    # replace every 0's in attn_tensor to -1
    torch.where(attn_tensor == 0.0, torch.tensor(-2.0), attn_tensor)

    for m in range(test_i.size()[1]):

        input_ids = test_i[:,m]
        input_ids = torch.tensor(input_ids.tolist()).unsqueeze(0) 
        outputs = best_model(input_ids)

        for k in range(test_i.size()[0]):

            for j in range(nlayer):

                # extract mean attention weights of batch m, token k, at layer j
                # (i.e. across all heads and the sequence)
                #
                attn_mean_list_k = []

                attn_mean = torch.mean(outputs[4][j][0,:,:,k])
                attn_mean = [attn_mean]
                attn_mean_list_k = attn_mean_list_k + attn_mean

            for z in range(len(attn_mean_list_k)):

                attn_mean_list_chunk_k = attn_mean_list_k[:z+1]
                attn_tensor[m,z,k] = multiply_list(attn_mean_list_chunk_k)

    return attn_tensor

# execute attain_weight_loop
attn_tensor_Wiki103 = attn_weight_loop(test_Wiki103_iter, nlayer, best_GPT2_Wiki103)
```

After I finish running this code on my Amazon EC2 instance, how can I retrieve and view the resulting `attn_tensor_Wiki103` from my computer?

Thank you,

Comment: are you familiar with `ssh`? if the output is being saved to disk on the instance that would be the most straightforward way to get it

Comment: I am not familiar with ```ssh```. How can I use ```ssh``` to get the results back?

Comment: my computer is Mac OS so I can run terminal

Comment: this is a lot more than I can explain in a comment. google how to ssh into an ec2 instance and there should be plenty of information for you on how to do it